# Writing Snake game, unable to have multiple blocks in Snake

Tags: java

I'm writing a Snake program and trying to make it so eating each piece of food increases the Snake length. Instead what happens is the food and one-length Snake reset their positions. I'm not sure how to make it so that (for example), after eating one food, a new box appears in the prior location of the first box and the snake keeps going. Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Component.*;
import java.awt.Color.*;

import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Board extends GraphicsProgram 
{
  // constants
  private final int 
    APPLICATION_WIDTH = 300,
    APPLICATION_HEIGHT = 300; // application width and height should be equal

  private final int ALL_DOTS = 900;
  private final int DELAY = 100;

  ArrayList<GRect> snakeJoints = new ArrayList<GRect>();
  private Enemy enemy;
  private int dots, foodX, foodY;
  private int randPos = APPLICATION_WIDTH/10 - 1;
  private int dotSize = APPLICATION_WIDTH/30;
  private boolean right = false;
  private boolean left = false;
  private boolean up = false;
  private boolean down = false;
  private boolean gameOver = false;
  private GImage ball, food;
  private RandomGenerator rand;
  private GLabel gameLost;

  public void init()
  {
    setSize(APPLICATION_WIDTH + 3*dotSize, APPLICATION_HEIGHT + 8*dotSize);
    addKeyListeners();

    rand = new RandomGenerator();

    GRect dot = new GRect(dotSize, dotSize);

    snakeJoints.add(new GRect(dotSize, dotSize));
    snakeJoints.get(0).setFillColor(Color.RED);
    snakeJoints.get(0).setFilled(true);

    food = new GImage("food.png");
    food.setSize(.9 * dotSize, .9 * dotSize);

    setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    newSquare();

    placeFood();

    enemy = new Enemy(dotSize);
    add(enemy);
    enemy.setFillColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    enemy.setFilled(true);
    enemy.setLocation(rand.nextInt(1, randPos - 3)*dotSize, 
                      rand.nextInt(1, randPos - 3)*dotSize);
  }

  public void run() 
  {
    while (!gameOver) 
    {
      oneTimeStep();
      pause(DELAY);
    }
  }

  public void oneTimeStep()
  {
    checkLoseCollision();
    checkFood();
    move();
  }

  public void newSquare() 
  {
    snakeJoints.add(new GRect(dotSize, dotSize));
    snakeJoints.get(0).setFillColor(Color.RED);
    snakeJoints.get(0).setFilled(true);
    add(snakeJoints.get(0), APPLICATION_WIDTH/2, APPLICATION_HEIGHT/2);
  }

  public void placeFood() 
  {
    int i = (int) (Math.random() * randPos);
    foodX = ((i * dotSize));
    i = (int) (Math.random() * randPos);
    foodY = ((i * dotSize));
    add(food, foodX - dotSize, foodY - dotSize);
  }

  public void gameLost() 
  {
    gameOver = true;
    gameLost = new GLabel("Game Over", APPLICATION_WIDTH/2, 
                          APPLICATION_HEIGHT/2);
    gameLost.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    add(gameLost);
  }

  public void checkFood() 
  {
    if (snakeJoints.get(0).getBounds().intersects(food.getBounds())) 
    {
      remove(food);
      newSquare();
      placeFood();
    }
  }

  public void move()
  {
    for (int i = snakeJoints.size()-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      snakeJoints.get(i).setLocation(snakeJoints.get(i-1).getX(), snakeJoints.get(i-1).getY());
    }

    if (left)
    {
      snakeJoints.get(0).move(-dotSize, 0);
    }

    if (right)
    {
      snakeJoints.get(0).move(dotSize, 0);
    }

    if (up) 
    {
      snakeJoints.get(0).move(0, -dotSize);
    }

    if (down) 
    {
      snakeJoints.get(0).move(0, dotSize);
    }
  }

  public void checkLoseCollision() 
  {
    for (int i = dots; i > 0; i--) 
    {
      if ((i > 4) && (snakeJoints.get(0).getBounds().intersects
                        (snakeJoints.get(i).getBounds()))) 
      {
        gameLost();
      }
    }

    if (snakeJoints.get(0).getY() + dotSize > APPLICATION_HEIGHT || snakeJoints.get(0).getY() < 0)
    {
      gameLost();
    }

    if (snakeJoints.get(0).getX() + dotSize > APPLICATION_WIDTH || snakeJoints.get(0).getX() < 0)
    {
      gameLost();
    }

    if (snakeJoints.get(0).getBounds().intersects(enemy.getBounds()))
    {
      gameLost();
    }
  }

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
  {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
      left = true;
      right = false;
      up = false;
      down = false;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
      right = true;
      left = false;
      up = false;
      down = false;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
      up = true;
      down = false;
      right = false;
      left = false;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
      down = true;
      up = false;
      right = false;
      left = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void newSquare() 
  {
    snakeJoints.add(new GRect(dotSize, dotSize));
    snakeJoints.get(0).setFillColor(Color.RED);
    snakeJoints.get(0).setFilled(true);
    **add(snakeJoints.get(0), APPLICATION_WIDTH/2, APPLICATION_HEIGHT/2);**
  }
```

I believe your last line ( **add(snakeJoints.get(0), APPLICATION_WIDTH/2, APPLICATION_HEIGHT/2);** ) sets your snake to the center. Your call checkFood calls newSquare, which instead of adding new square at the end of your snake sets it to the center of the application window (dimensions/2).

Note that if your snake's head graphics is the same as the rest of it, you could basically change food into a square and then make it snake's new head (the effect is the same - the snake gets longer).

Answer (score 0):

In this piece of code you have a couple of problems:

```
public void newSquare() 
  {
    snakeJoints.add(new GRect(dotSize, dotSize));
    snakeJoints.get(0).setFillColor(Color.RED);
    snakeJoints.get(0).setFilled(true);
    add(snakeJoints.get(0), APPLICATION_WIDTH/2, APPLICATION_HEIGHT/2);
  }
```

`snakeJoins.add()` will add new joint to the end of the list, but you're then proceed to manipulate the first element. Moreover, you then set coordinates of the new join to the middle of the screen.

What I think you should do in oder to properly grow your snake is to check whenever your snake will eat the food *before* you move it. This way you can just make it so the food rectangle becomes the first joint of your snake and you no longer need to move it on this iteration.

EDIT: Some food for thought (pseudocode):

```
public void move()
  {
    for (int i = snakeJoints.size()-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      snakeJoints.get(i).setLocation(snakeJoints.get(i-1).getX(), snakeJoints.get(i-1).getY());
    }
    GRect newPosition = new GRect(snakeJoints.get(0).getBounds());
    if (left)
    {
      newPostition.setLocation(newPostition.getX()-dotSize, newPosition.getY());
    }

    if (right) {//etc
    }

    if (intersectsWithFood(newLocation) {
      //repaint food as snake joint
      food.setFillColor(Color.RED);
      food.setFilled(true);
      snakeJoints.addFirst(food); //add food as a joint
      createFood();//create another food
    } else {
      snakeJoints.get(0).setLocation(newLocation.getX(), newLocation.getY());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Byakuya 

Thanks for the idea, guys. You both suggest that I turn the food into the head of the snake upon collision. Could you elaborate how I might go about doing that? I'm taking a programming class for the first time, and I'm still getting used to the syntax.